# "Functional Blocks" in kicad

Tags: kicad, eda

I have a schematic that I'm making that uses the same "block" multiple times.  I would like to design that block only once, and then use it in a bunch of different places, so I can edit the block if I like and have that edit show up everywhere.

Hierarchical sheets seem to be the way to do this, however you can't import a single sheet multiple times.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you can't import the same sheet multiple times? That would seem to be a huge handicap and almost defeat the purpose of the feature in the first place.

Comment: It would seem to defeat the purpose, but the button on the side, and the menu dropdown both won't let you use the same sheet over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use hierarchical sheets multiple times. With advantage you can use hierarchical connectors. Multi units components work correctly as well. Note you can always edit sheet properties using **E** key, i.e. change file name and sheet name.

[image]

Comment: Ah!, so you need to name the block differently, but use the same schematic sheet?

Comment: Yes, AFAIR it was slightly tricky but I did it ;-)

Comment: Yep, just use the same .sch file! You'll need to re-add your hierarchical pins in the new sheet. Works in KiCad 4.0+ (Ubuntu).